# Как добавить картинкам внутренние рамки при наведении?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть картинки, у которой по задумке должна при наведении появляться внутренняя рамка. Как это можно сделать, если картинки все разных размеров (нельзя использовать позиционирование с заданными размерами), их нельзя изначально обрезать (прозрачными `border`) и все должно быть кроссбраузерно `ie9+` ?
Есть ли для этого какой-то хитрый способ (понятно, что я имею ввиду без скриптов)?

```css
img:hover {
  outline: 6px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
.border {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.border::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  transition: box-shadow .1s ease;
}
.border:hover::after {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b-pict {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.b-pict img {
  display: block;
}
.b-pict:before {
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-pict:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-pict">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
<div class="b-pict">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
</div>
<div class="b-pict">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
</div>
```

[Пример в fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/28wby02g/)